# How to delete nested panel

Tags: extjs

I have a nested panel like:

```
Ext.define('Demo.view.example', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
     requires:[
            'Ext.toolbar.Paging'
    ],
    xtype: 'demo-view-example',

    autoScroll: true,

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        pack: 'start',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    frame: true,


    initComponent: function() {
        Id = this.Id;
        var store = Ext.create('Demo.store.example');
        store.proxy.url = store.proxy.url + this.Id;
        Ext.apply(this, {
            store: store
        });

        this.items = [],
        this.bbar = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
            store: store,
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
            listeners: {
                beforechange: function(obj){
          obj.up().removeAll();//to remove its children also
              }
            }
        }),

        this.callParent();
    },
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(obj){
          var panel =  Ext.create('Demo.view.example1',{
     });
    obj.add(panel);
        obj.doLayout();
    }
});
```

Here, I am adding a panel dynamically.In before change fuction, I am removing the component but It doesnot remove the children (nested panels).

Code for example1:

```
Ext.define('Demo.view.example1', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    xtype: 'demo-view-example1',

    autoScroll: true,
    defaults: {
        frame: false
    },

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        pack: 'start',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    initComponent: function() {


        this.items = [{
            xtype: 'demo-view-example2',
            flex:2
        }];

        this.callParent();
        if (this.requestId) {
            var requestContainerPanel = Ext.create({
                    xtype: 'demo-view-example3',
                    flex: 6
                });
            this.add(requestContainerPanel);
        } 
        this.doLayout();
    }

});
```

Here, I am adding one static view(example3) and dynamic view(example4) both extends from Ext.panel.Panel

Question:
In view(example) In before Change function, I am removing the component but it only removes obj of example. I want to remove all the views(example,example1,example2,example3). how should I do it.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue copying your code into fiddle (Sencha Fiddle) and the removeAll method worked as expected. Can you please try to provide a fiddle so I can take a look?

Comment: this is a part of my whole code.After this what I am doing is in example 3 view, I have buttons in  items and it is associated with the store. I am reloading the store every 3 seconds by starting a task.Now if I am deleting the obj from example view and adding the new but same layout again It is showing the previous button idand new button id both. Is it due to reloading of the store every 3 seconds(It is not allowing the previous created button object to delete)

Comment: But as I said, I copied this code to Sencha Fiddle ran it and it removed all the panels without any issues. So if you could try creating a Fiddle where your issue happens someone here may be able to help you.